# Use 'ScriptEngine' to calculate formula without losing any precision

Tags: javascript, java, math, decimal

Can `ScriptEngine`'s calculation have no accuracy lose? I use it to calculate `+`, `-` and `*` in java.

```
 ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByExtension("js");
 String calFormula = "5.08*8.99+3.23*4.221";
 Object obj = engine.eval(calFormula);
```

What it returns is a `Double`. I want something like `BigDecimal`.

Or must I implement this by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to implement this by yourself.

Just need to choose another scripting language, because JavaScript does all math in `double`.

Groovy defaults to `BigDecimal`, so that would seem a better fit.